# Apply formula in visible rows that is filtered

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 sheets the filtered one and the reference sheet

[Main Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrDQf.jpg)

This image contains the filtered rows and I want to reference its values from another sheet.

This my formula: 
`=IF(ISBLANK('April Espino'!N2),"",'April Espino'!N2)`

But when I fill it down the reference point skips the specific rows in the main sheet.

E.g.

`=IF(ISBLANK('April Espino'!N2),"",'April Espino'!N2)`

`=IF(ISBLANK('April Espino'!N4),"",'April Espino'!N4)`

`=IF(ISBLANK('April Espino'!N13),"",'April Espino'!N13)`

How can I do it sequentially?

Outcome :

N2

N3

N4

etc...

Comment: With an excel formula it would be a bit difficult to achieve it. With `VBA` it would be easier - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: @Vityata I just want to make the formulae fill the visible rows in reference to the other sheet. Is it necessary for me to use a `VBA` function?

Comment: Well, with excel formulas it is possible, but it is a lot more work and it requires some additional range... I think. And with `VBA` it will probably be more than a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `Row 1` is header row and you want formula in `Column C`, try this

```
=IF(ISBLANK(INDIRECT("'April Espino'!N"&COUNTA($C$1:$C1)+1)),"",INDIRECT("'April Espino'!N"&COUNTA($C$1:$C1)+1))
```

***NOTE:*** `INDIRECT` is a volatile function. See [this](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm) for details.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, sadly it doesn't return any results at all.

Comment: @Hibari - In which Column are you copying this formula? Enter this formula in `Cell C2` and drag/copy down.

Comment: In `Column N`, which contains the referenced value from `Sheet 2`.

Comment: @Mrig - the OP has values in the hidden rows, thus `CountA` would not be of use.

Comment: @Vityata - I'm using `CountA` on the column where formula is being entered and not against data sheet i.e.`April Espino`, so I guess this should work.

Comment: @Hibari - in `Cell N2` enter this formula  `=IF(ISBLANK(INDIRECT("'April Espino'!N"&COUNTA($N$1:$N1)+1)),"",INDIRECT("'April Espino'!N"&COUNTA($N$1:$N1)+1))`

Comment: @Hibari - Any luck?

Comment: @Mrig it returns a blank result.

Comment: @Hibari - Is `Column N` empty before entering formula? Or is it possible for you to share screen shot or your sheet with dummy data?